# String to Int 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

How do you fix the problem of

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19 at ProjectEuler11.main(ProjectEuler11.java:21)`.

Because what I am trying to do is to put all numbers to int 2D array from this String

```
class ProjectEuler11 {

public static void main(String []args) {

    String digitNumber = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 2124 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";

    String []numberVector = digitNumber.split(" ");
    int [][]digitNumberVector = new int[19][19];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int answerNumber = 0;

    for(int parameter2 = 0; parameter2 < 20; parameter2++) {

        for(int parameter3 = 0; parameter3 < 20; parameter3++){

            for(String parameter : numberVector) {

                x = parameter2;
                y = parameter3;
                digitNumberVector[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(parameter);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}// Java Document
```

Comment: You've declared `digitNumberVector` with a size of `[19][19]`, so when you attempt to set the 20th element (`[19]`), the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

```
new int[19][19]
```

In such array, elements are indexed 0...18. But in your for loops:

```
for(int parameter2 = 0; parameter2 < 20; parameter2++)
```

`parameter2` and `parameter3` take values 0...19, and this 19 is already out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

uchitha Kiripitige is correct, the array is indexed wrong.  Below is a correct version of your code that dynamically calculates the indices.  Also, I made a few performance optimizations to your code.

```
public class ProjectEuler11 {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String digitNumber = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 2124 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48 76";
        String []numberVector = digitNumber.split(" ");
        final int DIM = (int)Math.sqrt(numberVector.length + 1);
        int [][]digitNumberVector = new int[DIM][DIM];
        int vectorIdx = 0;
        for(int parameter2 = 0; parameter2 < DIM; parameter2++){

            for(int parameter3 = 0; parameter3 < DIM; parameter3++){
                digitNumberVector[parameter2][parameter3] = Integer.parseInt(numberVector[vectorIdx]);
                vectorIdx++;
            }
        }
    }
}// Java Document
```

As a side note, your digitNumber string only contained 399 values instead of 400 so I had to add an extra integer so the equal-sized for loops would work properly.